# Number of Isomorphism Classes of Corepresentations of A Compact Quantum Group

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Given a compact quantum group $(G,\Delta)$, with dense Hopf algebra $H$, is it always true that, up to isomorphism, $H$ will have a countable number of irreducible comodules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a discrete uncountable group G of cardinality M, then $C^*_r(G)$ will be a compact quantum group with M irreducible (1-dimensional) corepresentations.